# Correct way to use destructuring in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I get data from the database of which I only need two arrays. Using two variables, I get the result I need, but I understand, that this code is not written correctly. Even npm writes that the arrow function should return something, so I added "return false";

```
let flagUrls = [];
let countryNames = [];

country.map((country, index) => {
   flagUrls[index] = country.flagUrls;
   countryNames[index] = country.countryNames;
   return false;
});

this.setState({ flagUrls, countryNames });
```

I tried like this:

```
let flagsAndCountrys =  country.map((country, index) =>[country.flagUrls, country.countryNames])


this.setState({ 
   flagsAndCountrys.flagUrls,
   flagsAndCountrys.countryNames 
   });
```

Comment: This isn't really an issue regarding [destructuring assigment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), this is more of an issue of proper usage [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Array.prototype.map expects a return statement to create a new array of transformed results. Given you are trying to create two (2) arrays, `map()` is probably not the right array method to use. You could probably just use `forEach()` or even a for loop.

Comment: Maybe you can provide the what the data to `country` looks like and what you are expecting `flagUrls` and `countryNames` to look like after processing.

Comment: why would you want to seperate thAs I see it, you'll have to keep the two arrays in sync, or are you doing anything to these two lists where they will get out of sync? Like changing one array, but not the other. If not, then this is counter-productive; you change your data-structure into another one that is harder to reason about.

Comment: Just as @Thomas suggests: you may have an [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), as generally it is a good thing when corresponding data are coupled together in objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map`method creates a new array with the **return** value of the provided function on every element in the calling array.
Notice the word return in the above line. You need to return something that will be inserted in the new array.

So, using `map` you can create a new array, consisting of objects with only the `flagUrls` and `countryNames` field like so:

```
let result = country.map((country, index) => {
   return {
     flagUrl: country.flagUrls,
     countryName: country.countryNames
   }
});
```

If you want maintain two array of flagUrls and countryNames, you should not be using map. It's better to use forEach here, like so:

```
let flagUrls = [];
let countryNames = [];
country.forEach((country, index) => {
   flagUrls.push(country.flagUrls);
   countryNames.push(country.countryNames);
});
```

Using destructuring for this, replace the first parameter passed to the provided function `country` with the values like: `{flagUrls, countryNames}`

```
country.forEach(({flagUrls, countryNames}, index) => {
   flagUrls.push(flagUrls);
   countryNames.push(countryNames);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to create two arrays would be to call `map` twice:

```
const flagUrls = countries.map(country => country.flagUrl);
const countryNames = countries.map(country => country.countryName);
```

If you want to do it with only a single iteration, then you'll have to use a loop with side effects - similar to the `map` call you did, but you'd rather use `forEach`:

```
let flagUrls = [];
let countryNames = [];
countries.forEach((country, index) => {
    flagUrls[index] = country.flagUrl;
    countryNames[index] = country.countryName;
});
```

or just

```
let flagUrls = [];
let countryNames = [];
for (const country of countries) {
    flagUrls.push(country.flagUrl);
    countryNames.push(country.countryName);
}
```